# Image rotated by 0 degrees has a different base64 compared to the original image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I have rotated by 0 degrees on PIL, the exact command being:

```
image = Image.open("filename.jpg")
rotated = image.rotate(0,expand=True)
rotated.save("filename2.jpg")
```

The base64 or even the sha1 hash of both these images is quite different. If the angle of rotation is 0, why should this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `jpg` is [lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression), just opening a `jpg` file and saving it again will result in loss of information and a different hash.

With `png`, you might get the exact same file as long as no other information (e.g. header with modification time) is updated. The pixels won't be modified after a 0° rotation, but the compression algorithm might yield a different binary file even if the image itself hasn't been touched.

To debug this behaviour, you could try it with a `bmp` file, save it again without rotation, save it again with rotation and check the hashes.